# Inserting Newlines at the Bash Command Prompt

Tags: linux, bash

How can I add line breaks to a command at the prompt?

I know that when I copy a multiline command from the internet that has newlines it appears on the command line

```
$ something
> like
> this
```

Also I know that you can use `\` to insert a newline at the very end of your command

```
$ like \
> this
```

But how can I add newlines in the middle of a command that I've already typed out?

For example, given

```
$ this long command that I want to split over multiple lines
```

How can I turn it into

```
$ this long command
> that I want to split
> over multiple lines
```

So far I've tried:

- Using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> to insert a return character - just results in `^M` being inserted
- Typing <kbd>\</kbd> <kbd>return</kbd> in the middle of the input (as you would do at the end of a line) - just results in `\` being typed and then the command being executed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl+J</kbd>.

This inserts a linefeed character rather than a carriage return (which <kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> would result in after <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>).

Comment: Ah, so are carriage returns the characters used to submit a command at the prompt? If so then it makes sense why `Ctrl+V` and `Enter` would insert one - I was initially assuming that since Unix files use linefeed characters as line endings that `Ctrl+V` and `Enter` would insert one of these.

Comment: @JShorthouse The `Enter` key by itself sends the current line to the thing that reads it (the readline library). Prefixing it by `Ctrl+V` sends a carriage return. This does not mean that Unix uses carriage returns for newlines.